# React - Card Doesn't Show up

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React. I am going through a very interesting React project, called Covid-19 tracker, on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khJlrj3Y6Ls&t=3135s). 
I am facing an issue at 36:21, I am supposed to see Card like this:
[image]

Instead, I am seeing Card like this:

[image]
As you can see, the cards displaying the number of infected people are not showing up. How can I fix the issue?

Here are my codes in `Cards.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, CardContent, Typography, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import CountUp from 'react-countup';

import styles from './Cards.module.css';

const Cards = ({data: {confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate} }) => {
    if(!confirmed){
        return 'Loading...';
    }
    return(
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
                <Grid item component={Card}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Infected</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5">{confirmed.value}</Typography>
                            <CountUp
                                start={0}
                                end={confirmed.value}
                                separator={0}
                            />
                        <Typography color="textSecondary">Real Date</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2">Number of Activate Cases of COVID-19</Typography>
                    </CardContent>

                </Grid>
                <Grid item component={Card}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Recovered</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5">Real Data</Typography>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary">Real Date</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2">Number of Recoveries from COVID-19</Typography>
                    </CardContent>

                </Grid>
                <Grid item component={Card}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Deaths</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5">Real Data</Typography>
                        <Typography color="textSecondary">Real Date</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2">Number of Deaths Caused by COVID-19</Typography>
                    </CardContent>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Cards;
```

Here are my codes in `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Cards, Chart, CountryPicker} from './components';
import styles from './App.module.css';
import {fetchData} from "./api";

class  App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: {},
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const fetchedData = await fetchData();

        this.setState({data:fetchedData})
    }


    render() {
        const data = this.state;

        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <Cards data={data} />
                <Chart />
                <CountryPicker />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Here are my codes in `index.js`:

```
export { default as Cards } from './Cards/Cards'
export { default as Chart } from './Chart/Chart'
export { default as CountryPicker } from './CountryPicker/CountryPicker'
```

Here is the link to my project files:

Comment: It looks like you should look in your `fetchData` function. Does it return a value where `confirmed` is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything right in your fetch, you save data to state. But there is error when you initialize `const data = this.state` while in state you have object where is located data object. So because of nested object you cannot fetch confirmed in your Cards. 
Currently data object should look like

```
data{ data { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate }}
```

To solve this problem you should send `const data = this.state.data` like this

Comment: Yes! In `app.js` file, I change `const data = this.state;` to `const data = this.state.data;`. Now, the issue has been fixed. Thanks!